# NodeJS how copy files from the project directory to the execution directory?

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line-interface

I'm creating a cli - project-generator with NodeJS. I have the base project boilerplate in my nodeJS project-folder.
I will upload it to npm and I want that when the user exec my cli command, the boilerplate gets copyed from the nodejs project folder to the folder where the user execs the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 process.cwd()
```

Gets you the path to the dir where the cmd was executed